# How to find the second file in a folder in shell Scripting(unix)

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I want a command the will assing the name of the 2 file/folder in a folder to a variable. No files/folders are specific, I want this command to work on any folder.
For example:
If a do an ls in a folder it gives me:
     hey.txt
     hello
     lol
     yolo.png
And I want a command finding the second file/folder, in this case it is the folder hello. Then i want $WATHFILE to have the value hello. 
Thanks in advance.
Edit: Also, is there a way to change the what number of file to find, from the second file to the third, based on a variable?

Comment: What if there are < 2 files/folders in the folder ?

Answer (score 0):

This will set a variable with the second result:

```
var=$(ls | sed -n '2p')
```

Why do you want to set the builtin variable `$8` to this value?

Comment: That was just an example of what I could of done with it. But I changed my mind as soon as I published the question. OOPS.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for `sed` the stream editor.  You can pipe the output of `ls` through sed then extract the second word:

```
ls | sed -n 2p
```

Now you can do what ever you want with this output, such as store it to a variable:

```
foo=`ls | sed -n 2p`
```